# Is mixing ORM and explicit SQL in SQLalchemy bad practice?

Tags: sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I find that for setting up my database schema and running simple queries I prefer using SQLAlchemy's ORM. Sometimes however for queries involving complex joins it is easier and (I think) more readable to use plain SQL and `engine.execute`.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing inherently "wrong" with any approach to doing things in software development unless it doesn't work. There are tradeoffs for almost everything. Now, obviously, there are things that *most* people agree are bad practices (such as using GOTOs, and still there are some people that would make the argument there), but basically everything after that is just opinions. And StackOverflow tries to stay away from "opinions" (or at least explicitly acknowledge them as such). There are some that would say that using an ORM at all is a "bad practice" or "anti-pattern"!

Therefore, it's impossible to make one general, overarching, correct answer. However, here are some things to think about:

1. Is the time it takes to write the SQL using engine.execute more or less time than using the ORM (remember that you might also need to write some code to help translate the results into your own object model if necessary).
2. Assuming you had to make changes to this query, would modifying the raw SQL take more or less time than modifying the ORM-equivalent?
3. Basically, the same questions above, but now consider if OTHER PEOPLE ON YOUR TEAM are making the changes. Maybe someone isn't as familiar with SQLAlchemy model at all. Maybe this would be better off as a stored procedure all together?
4. Is the software you are writing designed to be able to be run on multiple databases? In that case, raw SQL is more likely to use a database dialect-specific syntax that could break on other databases. This also might change your ability to migrate to a different database in the future if necessary (or use a different database like SQLite to run fast tests against).

As you can see, it is completely legitimate for one project to choose one way, while another project to choose another way. It also is legitimate to use both methods in the same project. SQLAlchemy itself gives you the ability to choose how to use it, take advantage of that choice to use it the way that fits best for you and your specific cases.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. As this is a personal project which I'm certain will only ever be used on only SQLite and is not likely to be read by anyone else I'll stick to the current approach.

Answer (score 2):

While there's nothing wrong with it, and it may actually be the best way in some specific cases, in general it's not encouraged.  One of the points of using SQLAlchemy is that it abstracts away the differences between databases; writing explicit SQL may tie you to one database unnecessarily.  Once you get used to it, using the ORM queries is just as easy as writing SQL is for you now.